# the release flutter app crash when execute the Process.run

Tags: flutter, flutter-macos

I'm working on a flutter app, it works fine in develop mode, but after I use the command `flutter build macos` to build the app, when I open the app and when the function execute the command `var result = await Process.run(executable, arguments);`, the app will crash and close

I have tried to specify the absolutly path path of the executable(adb: /Users/teststststststs/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb), but it not work